# Enable permanently disabled project in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins, there is a Pull Request project which turns to disabled mode once it has been merged to the master. The behavior is correct, except that project is permanently disabled and I cannot enable it once again to remove it from the dashboard. The disabled/enabled option is greyed out. Cannot also remove the build and the pull request, still receives the error messages. Attached screenshots for verification.

Removed also content from the workspace.

[image: PR disabled]

[image: Remove of the build - error]

[image: Disable option]

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to enable an old PR? To do that you would need to push the branch and test with that.

If you are looking to get rid of the job, I beleive that you need to setup an orphaned-item-strategy
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline-as-code/#orphaned-item-strategy

This will clean up old branches and PRs after they have been merged

Comment: I have already set the "retention" options, so I will cut the days of the old item and I will see the result and let you know.

Comment: Ah yeah. In that case it is the orphaned item stuff you want.  Does drive me a little mad that I cannot manually clean them up :)

Comment: not helped, unfortunately :( still got the same error messages if I try to delete them.